# What is the complexity of counting the number of solutions of a P-Space Complete problem? How about higher complexity classes?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity, pspace

I guess it would be called #P-Space but I have found only one article vaguely mentioning it. How about the counting version of EXP-TIME-Complete, NEXP-Complete as well as EXP-SPACE-Complete problems? Is there any previous work that can one cite in regards to this or any type of inclusion or exclusion like Toda's Theorem?

Comment: You are asking a lot in one question!

Comment: #PSPACE is the same as the class of functions which can be computed in polynomial space (FPSPACE).

Comment: I think results for polytime transfer upwards using padding, don't they?

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi This is true. However, most of the questions asked if not all, can be rephrased as a single general question: Are there counting classes for classes higher than $NP$ (as one can note in the definition of #$P$) and do known results apply?

Comment: @Tayfun Pay: I'm not entirely sure what you mean for deterministic classes like PSPACE, EXP, EXPSPACE. The notion of "number of solutions" is usually closely tied to nondeterminism--since then you can ask about the number of accepting paths--or existential quantifiers/projections. In the case of PSPACE of course you can use the alternating quantifiers definition--but then you have to specify which quantifiers you want to count over--or the fact that NPSPACE=PSPACE.

Comment: As several comments mentioned, it is not totally clear what you would want to mean for #PSPACE.  The best bet would be to take the padded-up analog of #L which is well studied.  As #L is contained in DSPACE(log^2 n), this would imply that #PSPACE=PSPACE, as @TsuyoshiIto mentioned above.  (I am ignoring here the immaterial formal distinction between decision problems and functions.)

Answer (score -5):

The number of satisfying assignments to a boolean formula equals the number of valid quantifications of the formula.  The inductive proof is quite elegant. So #P = #PSpace.

Comment: Isn't this covered by Tsuyoshi and Noam's comments above?

Comment: Is this what you really mean? If #P = #PSPACE, doesn't this imply that PSPACE $\subseteq$ P$^{\#\mathrm{P}}$ ? I don't believe this is known.

Comment: @PeterShor I am fairly certain Daniel means this http://mathoverflow.net/a/12608/35733. But my (unverified) guess is that a #PSPACE-complete problem is to count the number of satisfying assignments of a fixed QBF, not count the number of satisfiable quantifications of a given CNF.

Comment: No, I meant that the number of valid quantifications of a given cnf equals the number of satisfying assignments of the cnf, given a fixed ordering of the variables.  Its very interesting in that changing the order of variables changes the valid qbfs, but not the total number of valid qbfs.