# Is there a counting complexity class for succint problems?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, counting-complexity, nexp, succinct

Encoding NP-complete problems succintly often makes them NEXP-complete. I am wondering if counting the number of solutions to such a problem with a succint encoding would be any harder than solving the original succint problem.

For instance, if we use a circuit encoding to represent a 3CNF formula, we obtain SUCCINCT 3SAT, which is NEXP-complete. What is the complexity of counting the number of satisfying assignments to a 3CNF formula represented as a circuit?

#NEXP would be a natural name for the resulting class, but I cannot find any reference to such a class. Can it be easily shown to be equivalent to NEXP?

The following question is related, but maybe focussing on NEXP which exhibits non-determinism would make it easier to find an appropriate answer.
[What is the complexity of counting the number of solutions of a P-Space Complete problem? How about higher complexity classes?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/what-is-the-complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-solutions-of-a-p-space-complete)

Comment: I guess the "natural" counting complexity class related to $\mathsf{NEXP}$ is $\#\mathsf{EXP}$ rather than $\#\mathsf{NEXP}$ and you shall find some papers on this. Also, this question (and the comments therein) is directly related to your question: [$\#\mathsf{EXP}$-Complete problems](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/22116/976).